# How To Space Out & Align (LI) Links In A Non-Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: css

How do I align the links within the Top Nav Bar. I understand trying to position `li` links is a lot more difficult than using `<divs>`.

**Code:** HTML & CSS
**Examples:** 4 x Diagrams (A, B, C, D) + Fiddle Detailed Below
**Nav Bar Attributes:** Fixed (Top) & Responsive - Mobile View < 800px, `Width=100%`
**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/tqam2sbd/

**A - Current - Regular View (>800px)**
| LINK 1 | LINK 2 | LINK 3 | LINK 4 | LINK 5 | **SPACE** | LINK 7 | LINK 6 |

**B - Current - Responsive Stacked View (<800px)**
| LINK 1 |
| LINK 2 |
| LINK 3 |
| LINK 4 |
| LINK 5 |
| LINK 6 |
| LINK 7 |

**C - Current - Regular View WITHOUT `class="right"` For LINK 6 & 7 (>800px)**
| LINK 1 | LINK 2 | LINK 3 | LINK 4 | LINK 5 | LINK 6 | LINK 7 |

**D - Expected / Desired - Regular View (>800px)**
| **START-SPACE** | LINK 1 | **SPACE** | LINK 2 | LINK 3 | LINK 4 | LINK 5 | **SPACE** | LINK 6 | LINK 7 | **END-SPACE** |

**Q1** - How do I achieve the **Diagram D** representation of the Nav Bar?

**CSS Code**

```
    ul.topnav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2F2E2E;
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {    
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
    color: #B0AAA9;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    color: #B0AAA9;
}

ul.topnav li.right {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    ul.topnav li.right,
    ul.topnav li {
        float: none;
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">allegiance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">faq</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">login</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">register</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're asking too many questions at once. It'd be helpful to show the code you've tried and then ask one specific question for each thing you're trying to do.

Comment: Waw that's thorough but way to much. First of, you have four _different_ questions in what should be one question. Your question itself also contains no code. You might want to prune and hone in on the essentials a bit more. Simply post the relevant HTML, CSS and JS as is and then ask us how to fix/improve/make-it-work this.

Comment: I'll post the code now. I have it linked above in Fiddle. I thought it would be easier to view it there as a whole instead of me pasting the code with no HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great example of a place to use `display: flex;`. CSS tricks has a handy [visual reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to easily see which properties do what you want.

I made a few changes to your html, I decided to treat each "group" of items as its own list item and combined the other list items. I also added a div before the page content to push it down below the navbar.

Then, by adding the following rules, your navbar's space works as desired. [Updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tqam2sbd/5/).

```
ul.topnav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
ul.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navspace {
    height: 45px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    ul.topnav {
        display: inherit;
        position: static; //a fixed navbar on mobile of this size makes the page unusable. 
    }
    ul.topnav a {
        display: block;
    }
    .navspace {
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually was on that site last night trying to figure it out but was trying to use the grid model instead of flexbox. :)

Comment: @AndrewGaw While this is possible without using flexbox, it will be way more work and I'm not sure I can see any benefit to going that route.

Comment: Where would I put the `.item {
  flex-grow:2;
}` to push the left & right links closer to the border edge of the page. I've been trying a few places, but it doesn't respond for me. I tried `ul.topnav  a { flex-gro:2;}` but if I understand correctly, that does nothing as it's the container for the links?

Comment: @AndrewGaw, does just changing space-around to space-between do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/tqam2sbd/6/

Comment: In this case, you would want to apply the item class to the li elements as they are what is being used to align everything.

Comment: Thanks again, this is awesome. Changing the space-around to space between was exactly what I was looking for. Lol, I've literally spent the whole day attempting to apply the flex-grow but not getting it correct. Thanks for the help. I'm actually working on the some JS to make the burger icon appear when the screen width reduces. CSS is tough, but I like what you can do with it.